# Does the $_FILES array get deleted after it's used in a function?

Tags: php, file-upload

I am resizing an image from a user upload form, and I have passed the contents of the `$_FILES` array to my resizing function. The function uses GD to resize the image and save it in the desired directory.

I need to make two copies of the image: a large copy and a small copy for a thumbnail. The problem arises when I try to call the function for a second time (but with different dimensions) to make the thumbnail image. I get an `unidentified index` array message for the `$_FILES` array.

Is the `$_FILES` array being deleted automatically after passing it to the function, despite the fact that I have not used the functions to clear it?

FUNCION CALL is as follows

```
   if ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 4){
foto($_FILES['image'], $THUMBS_DIR, 400, 400, 1);
foto($_FILES['image'], $THUMBS_DIR, 70, 70, 1);
}
```

FUNCTION

```
    /*foto function, foto upload, where to save, fotowidth, fotosize,*/
function foto($_FILES, $THUMBS_DIR, $MAX_WIDTH, $MAX_HEIGHT){

/*generate random name*/
$fecha = time();$passpart1 = $fecha;$passpart2 = mt_rand(1, 1000);$ps = $passpart1.$passpart2;$ps2= $passpart1.$passpart2.'thumb';$thumbref='0';    
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name']))

{
/*resize ratio*/
$original = $_FILES['tmp_name'];
list($width, $height, $type) = getimagesize($original);
if ($width <= $MAX_WIDTH && $height <= $MAX_HEIGHT) {$ratio = 1;}
elseif ($width > $height) {$ratio = $MAX_WIDTH/$width;}
else {$ratio = $MAX_HEIGHT/$height;}

$imagetypes = array('/\.gif$/','/\.jpg$/','/\.jpeg$/','/\.png$/');
$name = preg_replace($imagetypes, '', basename($original));

$name=$ps;switch($type) 
{case 1:$source = @ imagecreatefromgif($original);if (!$source) {$result = 'Cannot process GIF files. Please use JPEG or PNG.';}break;
 case 2:$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($original);break;
 case 3:$source = imagecreatefrompng($original);break;
 default:$source = NULL;$result = 'Cannot identify file type.';}

 if (!$source) {$result = 'Problem copying original';}

 else {
 $thumb_width = round($width * $ratio);
 $thumb_height = round($height * $ratio);
 $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
 imagecopyresampled($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $width, $height);
 switch($type) 
 {case 1:if (function_exists('imagegif')) {$success = imagegif($thumb, $THUMBS_DIR.$ps.'.gif');$thumb_name = $ps.'.gif';}
 else {$success = imagejpeg($thumb, $THUMBS_DIR.$ps.'.jpg', 50);$thumb_name = $ps.'.jpg';}break;

 case 2:$success = imagejpeg($thumb, $THUMBS_DIR.$ps.'.jpg', 100);$thumb_name = $ps.'.jpg';break;
 case 3:$success = imagepng($thumb, $THUMBS_DIR.$ps.'.png');$thumb_name = $ps.'.png';}

 /*destroy temp or not*/
 if ($success) {$result = "$thumb_name created";}

 }
 $fotref = $thumb_name;



 } 
 else{$errorreport='error with upload';}}
```

Hello again i have posted the code, I didnt originally post it becuase i didnt expect people to want to see it , I really appreciate it, Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your code?

Comment: Be sure to check the size of the file does not exceed `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` ini directives

Comment: Can you include the relevant functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is because $_FILES is a superglobal, and thus when you use it as the argument name in your function foto, it gets clobbered, such that $_FILES becomes whatever you passed as the first argument.

Rewrite the foto function with a variable besides $_FILES, e.g.:

```
function foto($image, $THUMBS_DIR, $MAX_WIDTH, $MAX_HEIGHT){
    // rest of code here with $_FILES changed to $image
}
```

Alternatively, as $_FILES is a super global, you could skip using it as a parameter at all, changing the call to be:

```
foto($THUMBS_DIR, 400, 400, 1)
```

And the function to be of the form:

```
function foto($THUMBS_DIR, $MAX_WIDTH, $MAX_HEIGHT){
   //code placeholder 
   if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {       
       $original = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   //rest of code
}
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thankyou very much. I took your second peice of advice and worked straigh off, without and brain racking. 

Robert